# Content of <div> not displaying on Gridview row click event?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have added hyperlink on the rows of gridview.What i'm trying to do is when i click on any row a particular div content show.
This is below my .CS file code..`

```
protected void BindGridView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=VAIO\\SA;Uid=sa;pwd=ans23@#;database=Lepz;");
    conn.Open();
    string p = "SELECT content FROM content";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(p, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "SampleTable");
    GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["SampleTable"].DefaultView; ;
    GridView2.DataBind();
    string q=Request.QueryString["content"];


    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowIndex == GridView2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl P_div = (HtmlGenericControl)row.FindControl("abcd");
            P_div.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "LinkButton" instead of "HyperLink" in this case. And add a attribute "CommandName" to each LinkButton control. After that add following code in GridView RowCommand event:

```
if (e.CommandName == "divCom")
{
    WebControl wc = e.CommandSource as WebControl;
    GridViewRow row = wc.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    HtmlGenericControl P_div = (HtmlGenericControl)row.FindControl("p_div");
    P_div.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    WebControl wc = e.CommandSource as WebControl;
    GridViewRow row = wc.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    HtmlGenericControl P_div = (HtmlGenericControl)row.FindControl("p_div");
    P_div.Visible = false;
}
```

**Here "divCom" is CommandName attribute value of LinkButton control and "p_div" is ID of div control.**